# PC/SC Card Terminal reset on Windows lock

Tags: java, smartcard, pcsc

guys i have a problem and maybe you can help. I have written some code which automatically writes data to smart cards via a printer.

The Problem is, whenever im inactive and the Windows Screen is locked, automatically after 10 minutes and i can't disable it on this notebook, Windows seems to reset my connection to the Terminal and the chipwriting fails.

After some research i found out the windows resets the connection because of security reasons so that someone can log into Windows with a smart card.

The Connection is already exlusive.

so now the question, does anyone know how i can disable this function in Windows, or tell my Java Code to ignore this?

Hope you guys can help.

Regards

Comment: Does it help to send a harmless command to the card after 8 minutes, like GET DATA, to get a new time slot?

Comment: no, windows resets the connection so that the plug and play service can get a new card if inserted, this is used for log into windows. so while you are in "locked PC mode" the connection is always reseted, also when i try to make a timed reconnect, windows will reset the connection again